# How to interpolate data with timestamp indices in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, timestamp

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of timestamps and a column of values, and I want to do linear interpolation and get values for different timestamps.
The dataframe looks like this:

```
                  timestamp            c0
0  2014-01-01T00:00:03.500Z  38605.324219
2  2014-01-01T00:00:21.500Z  37872.890625
4  2014-01-01T00:00:39.600Z  38124.664062
6  2014-01-01T00:00:57.600Z  38185.699219
8  2014-01-01T00:01:15.700Z  38460.367188
```

I wrote a function like this to give original dataframe and get interpolated one:

```
def interp18to9(df):
        dates = pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[0]['timestamp']),
                              pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[-1]['timestamp']), freq='9S')
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        new_df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dates)
        new_df['c0'] = np.interp(x=dates,
                                 xp=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:]['timestamp']),
                                 fp=df.iloc[:]['c0'])
        return new_df
```

I get an error which says:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I couldn't find a solution to this problem from searching for previous cases, thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: @ArkF this line `new_df['c0'] = np.interp(x=dates,
                                 xp=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:]['timestamp']),
                                 fp=df.iloc[:]['c0']) `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using pandas' internal functions:

```
# 'floor' date to seconds
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime((df['timestamp'].
                                  astype(np.int64)//10**9 * 10**9).astype('datetime64[ns]'))

# new range
new_range = pd.date_range(df.timestamp[0], df.timestamp.values[-1], freq='9S')

# resample and interpolate
df.set_index('timestamp').reindex(new_range).interpolate().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
+----+----------------------+--------------+
|    |        index         |      c0      |
+----+----------------------+--------------+
| 0  | 2014-01-01 00:00:03  | 38605.324219 |
| 1  | 2014-01-01 00:00:12  | 38239.107422 |
| 2  | 2014-01-01 00:00:21  | 37872.890625 |
| 3  | 2014-01-01 00:00:30  | 37998.777343 |
| 4  | 2014-01-01 00:00:39  | 38124.664062 |
| 5  | 2014-01-01 00:00:48  | 38155.181640 |
| 6  | 2014-01-01 00:00:57  | 38185.699219 |
| 7  | 2014-01-01 00:01:06  | 38323.033204 |
| 8  | 2014-01-01 00:01:15  | 38460.367188 |
+----+----------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get an error like this `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2014-01-01T00:00:03.500Z'`

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your `timestamp` was already in `datetime` format. Try to run `df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])` before the above code.

Comment: The original timestamps are changed by the answer, are there other alternatives were the original timestamps stay unchanged?